# UnsatisfiedLinkError when switch to Temurin Alpine from AdoptOpenJDK Alpine

Tags: glibc, alpine-linux, musl, eclipse-temurin

My project has shard libraries we load into Java via `System.load()`. Previously, we were using the AdoptOpenJDK Alpine docker image, but we are now trying to migrate to the Eclipse Temurin Alpine image. With the former image, everything works, but when trying to switch to the new image, the `System.load()` throws a `UnsatisfiedLinkError` for an image that should have already been loaded. My guess is this has to do with the swap from `glibc` to `musl`, but it seems odd that `musl` wouldn't work right out of the box like `glibc` did.

Example:

```java
System.load("/path/first.so");
System.load("/path/second.so"); // UnsatisifiedLinkError: /path/first.so: Error loading shared library second.so: No such file or directory (needed by /path/first.so)
```